# Error saving string in file Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have the following code:

```
print(title)
f = io.open("1.txt", "a", encoding="utf-8")
f.write(title + '\n')
f.close()
```

I get error:

> TypeError('can only concatenate list (not "str") to list',))

I use Python 3.5

Comment: You have to cast it to string type

Comment: Can you give some more context? What is the variable `title`, and which line is the error occurring on?

Comment: What does it mean?

Comment: `title` is string as `Mortal Combat`

Comment: `title`seems to be a list and not a string. You should provide the line in which `title``gets it's value in the question, so we can see what's wrong and how to solve it.

Comment: How can I see what is `title`?

Comment: You can try loading it to a file. Python should print it with the square brackets, though. Try doing `title[0]` instead, if it doesn't work then `title` isn't a list.

Comment: It is just string: `print("TITLE:" + title)`  get `TITLE:Surah Yaseen`

Comment: You could try `print(type(title))`. But since you have the code, share it. If you think it's a string but it isn't there might be a mistake in the definition of `title`.

Comment: Are you *sure* this error happens in this line?

Comment: Comment the last 3 lines and just show the output of `print(title)`

Comment: Works for me.  Either `title` is not a string, or you are making a false assumption as to the line that is causing the error.

Answer (score 1):

You can convert a List to a string using the  join function:

```
" ".join(["This", "is", "a", "list", "of", "strings"])
>>> This is a list of strings
```

In Python we usually write/read files using the "with-syntax":

```
with open('workfile.txt', 'w') as f:
     f.write("My entry line\n")
     f.write(" ".join(["Other", "line", "here"]))
     f.write("\n")
```

Comment: So, I have string, not `list`

Comment: are you saying that in your Python interpreter, `"string 1" + "string 2"` will raise a `TypeError` exception?

Comment: Seems it happend here: `f.write(url + '\n')`

Comment: there must be something missing in your question/assumptions.... this error should never been raised if you are really using 2 strings.

Answer (score 1):

Is `title` a variable of type string?

Your code runs without errors in this example:

```
import io
title = "My Title"
print(title)
f = io.open("1.txt", "a", encoding="utf-8")
f.write(title + '\n')
f.close()
```

To be save you can cast `title` to string by writing:

```
str(title)
```

You can check the type of a variable for string this way:

```
if type(title) is str:
    print("It's a string")
```

If you happen to have a list as input, please refer to the solution suggested by Jeanderson Barros Cândido.

Comment: Can you show us the line where you set `title` to a value?

Could it be that the error message in your question refers to another line in your script?